# Asymptotic expansion of Bessel function of the first kind, order zero

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

What would the asymptotic expansion of the following Bessel function look like?

$$J_0(2i\sqrt{x})$$

There are examples that show that the result is

$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{(2!)^2}+\frac{x^3}{(3!)^2}+...,$$

but these do not give the solution procedure.

Comment: Asymptotic with respect to what limit? Small or large $x$? Note that you can re-write your function as $I_0(2\sqrt{x})$ in terms of the modified Bessel function.

Comment: You ask a question. Ten minutes later, @Gary asked the key question. 21 hours later, no answer. Are you sure that you need help ?

Comment: @Gary What exactly would be "small" and "large"? Say that it ranges from 0.1 to 100.      

Claude While I appreciate the super fast answer, not each question is a matter of life and death. Users not replying within the day happens all the time on fora like these.

Comment: @DozerD Asymptotic expansions are developed about certain points usually about infinity or zero. A Maclaurin series such as the one you describe is a convergent power series, which fits the definition of an asymptotic expansion but it is unnecessary to call it as such. The interesting asymptotic expansions are the divergent ones. Your function admits such an expansion at $+\infty$. Anyway, you are interested in the proof of the Maclaurin series. The short answer is that it is the definition of $J_0$. What is your definition of $J_0$?

Comment: @Gary Thanks again for the reply, I was unaware that it is the definition of $J_0$. I realize that the question itself was not very well put.